# Russell's Paradox for the zero set and a set with the zero set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, paradoxes

So I have a question:

Let: Allow set B = {x: x $\notin$ x}. Then, B $\in$ B $\iff$ B $\notin$ B ?
Does this apply for the zero set?

Because I'm a bit confused. The definition is a zero set is always in the zero set. But then if $\emptyset$ $\in$ $\emptyset$, then $\emptyset$ $\in$ $\emptyset$ $\iff$ $\emptyset$ $\notin$ $\emptyset$.

Is there a mistake I'm making? Something doesn't feel right here. Sorry if it's a confusing question. (I don't know if this has been posted before?)

Also:

Let C = {$\emptyset$}. Is there an element? Because if there's an element, what is that element? Is it the empty set? If it's the empty set, then there's no set there is there? It's nothing in the set in there. But there's a set in there. (Please explain this also).  Can somebody also explain if I placed the logic of Russell's Paradox in this set with empty set?

Thank you for the help. (Thank you everybody) ありがとう 皆さん

Comment: The axioms of set theory state that the empty set (what you're calling the zero set) is a /subset/ of every set, not /in/ every set, which should clear up the $\emptyset \in \emptyset$ problem. Further, what you call $C = \{ \emptyset\}$ is a well-defined set and the member is the empty set. Imagine you had an empty box. There's nothing in the box, but the box itself exists, right? Now imagine you put the empty box inside of another box. That gives us $C = \{ \emptyset\}$. The box $C$ isn't empty, it has an empty box in it!

Comment: SO if I say that ∅ ∈ ∅, it would be false right? Its a proper subset with ∅ $\subset$ ∅? Is that the definition? So, is it a subset of itself? I think I'm confusing a law here.

Comment: Yes, that is false. By stipulation, for any object in the universe of discourse $X$, $X \not \in \emptyset$, and $X$ is always in our universe. Further, something /cannot/ be a proper subset of itself, so $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$. Finally, any set always has the following two subsets: itself and the empty set. In this case "itself" and empty set coincide, which is fine.

Comment: I see. The set is there, but it holds an element (namely the $\emptyset$). But because {$\emptyset$} holds the $\emptyset$, it's not empty (theres an element called "no element" in there. Also I think I get the subset thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition ***no set*** is an element of $\varnothing$, in particular itself. So it is not true that $\varnothing\in\varnothing\iff\varnothing\notin\varnothing$.

For the second part you're confusing "being empty" and "non-existing". If my wallet is empty, it doesn't mean that I don't have a wallet. The empty set is just a set which has no elements, it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. $\{\varnothing\}$ has a single element, and that element is the empty set. It doesn't mean that there are no elements there, since sets can be elements of other sets as well.

---

In any case, the Russell paradox comes to show that not every "property" defines a set. In particular the set $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ cannot exist. That's all that it shows. It says nothing about $\varnothing$ or otherwise.

Comment: I think I get it. So $\emptyset$ $\in$ { $\emptyset$}. There's an element in it, but it's nothing. It holds nothing. Where the empty set is nothing. I see now, and Russell's Paradox specifies only for sets with elements in it, not the empty set? (edit, I made the mistake of the $\emptyset$ $\subset$ {$\emptyset$})